# use Rails date_select with Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

How do you use Rails `date_select` form helper and generate a seperate `ng-model` for month and for year?

// Slim

`= f.date_select :from, { 
       order: [:month, :year],
       start_year: Time.now.year,
       end_year: 1990,
       include_blank: true },
       { :'ng-required' => 'isRequired'
       }`

The `date_select` makes it easy to set differenct prompts per each field. Is there any way to do this with your custom attributes?

`date_select("article", "written_on", prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' })`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `date_select` creates 3 `select_tag` fields(one for month, year, and day).  You can add the `ng-model` tag within `html_options` for `date_select`, but the problem is that all 3 select fields will have an identical `ng-model` tag with the same name.  Angular doesn't like having multiple `ng-model` objects with the same name, and I don't know how to get around this.  The solution I used was just to recreate what `date_select` does and create 3 `select_tag` fields.  It's definitely not as elegant as the `date_select` field but it does work.  I'd love to hear if anyone has a better solution!